# When I update android studio from 4.1 to 4.1.1 in windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.1

I got this error while updating android studio from version 4.1 to version 4.1.1 in windows 10.
I closed android studio from Task Manager and run android studio as Administrator but same error.

Following error output is in C:\Users%User%\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\log\idea_updater.txt

```
12/11 16:37:42 ERROR Runner.install - prepare failed
java.io.IOException: Data error (cyclic redundancy check)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at com.intellij.updater.Digester.doDigestStream(Digester.java:110)
    at com.intellij.updater.Digester.digestStream(Digester.java:103)
    at com.intellij.updater.Digester.digestRegularFile(Digester.java:55)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.digestFile(Patch.java:469)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchAction.isModified(PatchAction.java:187)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchAction.doValidateNotChanged(PatchAction.java:155)
    at com.intellij.updater.BaseUpdateAction.validate(BaseUpdateAction.java:92)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.lambda$validate$0(Patch.java:306)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.forEach(Patch.java:457)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.validate(Patch.java:305)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.prepareAndValidate(PatchFileCreator.java:55)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.install(Runner.java:357)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.main(Runner.java:138)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to invalidate Cache and restart. if still not working then you need to delete some files.

1. C:\Users<UserName>.gradle\cache // rename cache to cache.bak
2. C:\Users<UserName>.android\cache  // rename cache to cache.bak
3. C:\Users<UserName>.android\cache-build  // rename cache to cache-build.bak
4. C:\Users<UserName>.AndroidStudio3.6\system\cache   // rename to cache.bak
5. C:\Users<UserName>.AndroidStudio3.6\system\compiler  // rename to compiler  .bak
6. C:\Users<UserName>.AndroidStudio3.6\system\compile-server  // rename to compile-server.bak
7. C:\Users<UserName>.AndroidStudio3.6\system\external_build_system   // external_build_systemto cache.bak

**Hopefully! it will work...**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried your solution it doesn't work